# How to decode words in an NSString using a dictionary with keys and values of codes?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have textual reports that are coded with special shortcuts (i.e @"BLU" for @"BLUE", @"ABV" for @"Above", etc).

I created an NSDictionary where the keys are the coded word and values are the translations.

Currently I translate the string using this code:

```
    NSMutableString *decodedDesc = [@"" mutableCopy];
    for (NSString *word in [self.rawDescriprion componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]) {
            NSString * decodedWord;
            if (word && word.length>0 && [word characterAtIndex:word.length-1] == '.') {
                decodedWord = [abbreviations[[word substringToIndex:word.length-1]] stringByAppendingString:@"."];
            } else
                decodedWord = abbreviations[word];
            if (!decodedWord)
                decodedWord = word;
            [decodedDesc appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",decodedWord]];
        }
        _decodedDescription = [decodedDesc copy];
```

The problem is that the words in the report are not always seperated by a space. Sometimes the are connected to other special characters, such as @"-" or @"/", the code ignores the word because something like @"BLU-ABV" is not in the dictionary keys.

How can I improve this code to ignore special chars while translating the words but preserving them in the translated NSString? For example @"BLU-ABV" would translate into @"Blue-Above".

Comment: why are you doing "`NSMutableString *decodedDesc = [@"" mutableCopy];`" to create your mutable string?  Just use "`NSMutableString *decodedDesc = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The solution is to enumerate the original NSString letter by letter. Each letter is added to a word until reaching a special char.

Upon reaching a special char, the translated word, followed by the special char, are dumped into the translated report (which is an NSMutableString) and the word variable is reset to @"".

Here is the code: (not including the dictionary or original NSString initialization)

```
__block NSString *word;
    NSCharacterSet *specialChars = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];

    [_rawDescriprion enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [_rawDescriprion length])
                                options:(NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences)
                             usingBlock:^(NSString *letter, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                                 if (!word)
                                     word = @"";
                                 //if letter is a special char
                                 if ([letter rangeOfCharacterFromSet:specialChars].location != NSNotFound) {
                                     //add old word to decoded string
                                     if (word && abbreviations[word])
                                         [decodedDesc appendString:abbreviations[word]];
                                     else if (word)
                                         [decodedDesc appendString:word];

                                     //Add the punctuation character to the decoded description
                                     [decodedDesc appendString:letter];
                                     //Clear word variable
                                     word = @"";
                                 }
                                 else { //Alpha-numeric letter
                                     //add letter to word
                                     word = [word stringByAppendingString:letter];
                                 }
                             }];
    //add the last word to the decoded string
    if (word && abbreviations[word])
        [decodedDesc appendString:abbreviations[word]];
    else if (word)
        [decodedDesc appendString:word];

    _decodedDescription = [decodedDesc copy];
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by

```
NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" -/"];
[self.rawDescription componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet];
```

where the characterSet contains the Characters you want to separate by or you can even define the CharacterSet with the letters that make out your words (only alphabetical or alphanumeric) and then use the `invertedSet`.

Comment: The problem is that you lose the punctuation when doing that. For example, the string @"BLU-ABV" will become @[@"Blue",@"Above"]. You lose the information about what punctuation character was used when trying to reconnect the words.

Comment: you are right, I forgot that. But then I think NSScanner is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use character set to separate it.

```
NSMutableCharacterSet* cSet = [NSMutableCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet];
// add your own custom character
[cSet addCharactersInString:@" "];
NSArray *comps = [self.rawDescriprion componentsSeparatedByString:cSet];
```

You can take a look at which character set is more suitable for your case at [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCharacterSet/characterIsMember:)

But I will say it should be punctuation.